Tanstack Router Link with search params where one key has multiple values
I'd like to provide a search property to my Link component where they query string key can have multiple values (an array)
<Link to="/foo/bar" search={{group_by: ['foo', 'bar']}} ...>

This does work, but the query string in the browser is shown like this:
?group_by=%5B"foo"%2C"bar"%5D

It does work technically. But I'd like it to be:
?group_by=foo&group_by=bar

but I don't know how to make that happen. If I try to set the query string to the to property
<Link to="/foo/bar?group_by=foo&group_by=bar" ...>

I get a type error (I'm using typescript) that the route is not any of those I've defined in my router config.

Hi,
It's normal that the link component will encode the url and it will become like as you shown!
But when you read it, it will return to json again.
For more information, please read this page:
https://tanstack.com/router/latest/docs/framework/react/guide/search-params#json-first-search-params
